# PHP Laravel code returns Error 500 with no warning or errors in log

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I've purchased a Laravel project and have a controller script/code which is causing me issues. I've updated my XAMPP to 7.3.3 and finished the installation, however, right at the very end it gives me Error 500.

After a few hours of debugging, I found that commenting the below lines out fixes the issue but then gives me bigger errors on the website. What's wrong with the code below?

Full code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use URL;
use DB;
use Hash;
use App\GeneralSetting;
use App\BusinessSetting;
use App\User;
use App\Product;

class InstallController extends Controller
{
    public function step0() {
        $this->writeEnvironmentFile('APP_URL', URL::to('/'));
        return view('installation.step0');
    }

    public function step1() {
        $permission['curl_enabled']           = function_exists('curl_version');
        $permission['db_file_write_perm']     = is_writable(base_path('.env'));
        $permission['routes_file_write_perm'] = is_writable(base_path('app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php'));
        return view('installation.step1', compact('permission'));
    }

    public function step2() {
        return view('installation.step2');
    }

    public function step3($error = "") {

        if($error == ""){
            return view('installation.step3');
        }else {
            return view('installation.step3', compact('error'));
        }
    }

    public function step4() {
        return view('installation.step4');
    }

    public function step5() {
        return view('installation.step5');
    }

    public function purchase_code(Request $request) {
        $request->session()->put('purchase_code', $request->purchase_code);
        return redirect('step3');
    }

    public function system_settings(Request $request) {
        $generalsetting = GeneralSetting::first();
        $generalsetting->site_name = $request->name;
        $generalsetting->address = $request->address;
        $generalsetting->phone = $request->phone;
        $generalsetting->email = $request->email;
        $generalsetting->save();

        $businessSetting = BusinessSetting::where('type', 'system_default_currency')->first();
        $businessSetting->value = $request->system_default_currency;
        $businessSetting->save();

        $this->writeEnvironmentFile('APP_NAME', $request->system_name);

        $user = new User;
        $user->name      = $request->admin_name;
        $user->email     = $request->admin_email;
        $user->password  = Hash::make($request->admin_password);
        $user->user_type = 'admin';
        $user->email_verified_at = date('Y-m-d H:m:s');
        $user->save();

        foreach(Product::all() as $product){
            $product->user_id = $user->id;
            $product->save();
        }

        $previousRouteServiceProvier = base_path('app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php');
        $newRouteServiceProvier      = base_path('app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.txt');
        copy($newRouteServiceProvier, $previousRouteServiceProvier);
        //sleep(5);
        return view('installation.step6');

        // return redirect('step6');
    }
    public function database_installation(Request $request) {

        if(self::check_database_connection($request->DB_HOST, $request->DB_DATABASE, $request->DB_USERNAME, $request->DB_PASSWORD)) {
            $path = base_path('.env');
            if (file_exists($path)) {
                foreach ($request->types as $type) {
                    $this->writeEnvironmentFile($type, $request[$type]);
                }
                return redirect('step4');
            }else {
                return redirect('step3');
            }
        }else {
            return redirect('step3/database_error');
        }
    }

    public function import_sql() {
        $sql_path = base_path('shop.sql');
        DB::unprepared(file_get_contents($sql_path));
        return redirect('step5');
    }

    function check_database_connection($db_host = "", $db_name = "", $db_user = "", $db_pass = "") {

        if(@mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name)) {
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function writeEnvironmentFile($type, $val) {
        $path = base_path('.env');
        if (file_exists($path)) {
            $val = '"'.trim($val).'"';
            file_put_contents($path, str_replace(
                $type.'="'.env($type).'"', $type.'='.$val, file_get_contents($path)
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

Piece of code that resolves error 500 (when removed/commented) but causes more problems:

```
$user->save();

foreach(Product::all() as $product){
    $product->user_id = $user->id;
    $product->save();
}
```

I have no clue why removing/commenting that bit of code out seems to work but I was hoping someone could explain?

Comment: Did you check both logs? There might be information in either the server error log or in the Laravel log, found in `storage/logs`

Comment: The most recent lines in Laravel log are:

#62 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#63 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#64 {main}
"}

Comment: Wow, that's way down the stack trace. Look further up to where the timestamp is, it will show the error message

Comment: Enable app_debug=true in .env file and run `php artisan config:cache` and `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: The error I get is: "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db_mydb.users' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `user_type`

Comment: It sounds like either the database_installation has not been done, or the user table wasn't completely migrated. Try running `php artisan migrate` on the command line.

Comment: "Nothing to migrate" is the returned output of php artisan migrate

Comment: You'll have to check and see if there's anything in the migrations folder. Since you purchased the project, you may need to contact the makers and find out what's missing from the migration. You can also try moving your part of the code to another part of the script, but I'm not sure where that would be.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was fixed. Solution below.

I followed Mayank Dudakiya's instruction and set the app_debug to true in the env file. That then enabled me to view all issues and I fixed them 1 by 1, there was a total of 4 major issues.

My actual issue was due to a innodb memory size in mysqld. A simple edit of the my.ini enabled me to set it from 5m to 500m and that fixed the issue, allowed the database to install correctly and voila.

Thank you to everyone who responded.